# How to save excel plot as image with python?

Tags: python, excel

I have excel sheet which contains plotted graph. I want to save these plots as jpeg image file with python. I know how to read data from excel file with python, is there any way of reading these images and saving them as jpeg?
The excel looks like following.
[image]

Comment: If you can extract the correct data from the excel file you could use a python library such as matplotlib to create and save the graphs as files. There are quite a few plotting libraries for python.

I doubt there is a direct way to read the graph and I don't think you can save graphs in excel as an image unless you import it to word first, but then that isn't python!

Comment: @GeorginaS I know but the data is very complicated and to generated the same graph will consume time with matplotlib, I am searching for a way toget the plot which are created by the excel.